Can I change focal length of a camera from its ending point?
So you know how when you change a camera focal length it goes like this:

I would like to know if it's possible for it to change from this point instead:


You might want to search about camera rigs. It's a combination of camera, empty objects and drivers that let you edit camera properties by moving things.

This rig might be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPEh6ydPGpQ
